# Doctrings of Properties

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I access a property's docstring and not that of the value it holds?

Why do the 2 help functions in the code below return different docstrings for `abc.x`?

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    def getx(self):
        print "** In get **"
        return self._x

    x = property(getx, doc="I'm the 'x' property.")

abc = C()
help(abc) # prints the docstring specified for property 'x'
help(abc.x) # prints the docstring for "None", the value of the property
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you evaluate `abc.x`, you invoke the access method. To fetch the property itself, you can refer to it as `C.x`. You can then get its docstring with `help(C.x)`. If you only have a class instance, you can get to the property via its class:

```
>>> help(abc.__class__.x)
Help on property:

    I'm the 'x' property.
```

Answer (score 7):

This happends because `abc.x` is resolved to `None`. Then `None` is being passed to `help()`.  Try this:

```
help(C.x)
```

Comment: Thanks, upvoted! I accepted alexis's answer because it also contains what to do in case you only have a class instance